# Is there any way to collect columnar data which was returned during the distinct multiple SQL select statements runs?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have this custom requirement to run the SQL view query only for the data that is changed rather than running it for all data that is out there.

Again as, it is a custom project, I figured out that there is only one field(Say ProgramID) to which each and every data is related(Not necessarily through constrains or Foreign Keys). Database can be updated from several places(Frontend application, Batch jobs codes, etc). So there's no way to figure out what data associated to what ProgramId got updated.

But since ProgramId is the related to everyone, It might have got used in every query that tries to update the database.

So I am depending on the ProgramId returned for various multiple independent queries.  IS there any way I can get that through Some data dictionary tables or dynamic performance view what all Columnar value got returned over a time period(In this case ProgramID from TABLE A).

For eg.

```
tableNAME "TEST"
ID PROGRAMID
1  X
2  Y
3  Z
4  A
5  B
```

Now Suppose First SQL query returns PROGRAMID X AND Z.
Second sql returns Y AND A

So the output I need is X,Z,Y,A.
This is irrespective of which SQL statement returns what since I don't know what queries were ran.
Output should be the returned data from the table over a period of time.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Are you looking for a solution like an audit table where snapshots of rows are collected during each edit, or something built-in such as [Oracle Flashback](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_flashback.htm)? What is it that you need exactly?

Comment: @MickMnemonic see if the e.g. in the question helps

Comment: So are you looking to audit every query that's being run against the database? I'm having difficulties understanding _why_ exactly would you want to do this, and what is your real use case.

Comment: I didn't quite got your question, but ORA_ROWSCN gives the most recent changes to the rows of a table. Be cautious its not accurate. Go through this links
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108845/getting-the-last-data-update-time-of-a-specific-table-in-oracle

Comment: From your description it sounds as if you want to know which rows were previously selected. There is no way that I am aware of to obtain this information.